# how to run multiple tasks in C#?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task

How to modify the following code and make it runs multiple tasks concurrently?

```
foreach (SyndicationItem item in CurrentFeed.Items)
{
    if (m_bDownloadInterrupted)
    break;

    await Task.Run( async () =>
    {
        // do some downloading and processing work here
        await DoSomethingAsync();
    }
}
```

I also need to make interruption and stop the process possible. Because my DoSomethingAsync method reads the tag (a global boolean value) to stop the process.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will process the items concurrently.

```
  Parallel.ForEach(CurrentFeed.Items, DoSomethingAsync)
```

To be able to cancel you can need a CancellationToken.

```
  CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
  ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions();
  po.CancellationToken = cts.Token;

  // Add the ParallelOptions with the token to the ForEach call
  Parallel.ForEach(CurrentFeed.Items,po ,DoSomethingAsync)

  // set cancel on the token somewhere in the workers to make the loop stop
  cts.Cancel();
```

For detail see (among other sources) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256691.aspx

Comment: Sorry, but how to interrupt and stop the process based on the method you provide? Because my DoSomethingAsync method reads tag to stop the process. thanks!

Answer (score 9):

No, that won't run them concurrently - you're *waiting* for each one to finish before starting the next one.

You could put the results of each `Task.Run` call into a collection, then await [`Task.WhenAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall.aspx) *after* starting them all though.

(It's a shame that `Parallel.ForEach` doesn't return a `Task` you could await. There may be a more async-friendly version around...)

Comment: sorry, I have await inside that task. forget to put it in. Then how could I resolve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: @Jon: `Parallel.ForEach` uses the calling thread as one of its parallel threads, so you can make it async-friendly by wrapping it in `Task.Run`.

Comment: @Jerry: `Task.Run` will work as expected with asynchronous lambdas as well as synchronous lambdas (it unwraps the asynchronous ones). So you can still put the results into a collection and then await `Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: @StephenCleary: Good point - it feels a little icky, but it would be considerably nicer than collecting the tasks manually.